# Django Select Query to Fetch Data form All Child Tables

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7, django-queryset

I have Django Models Says,

```
class JobApplication(models.Model):
    job_application_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    resume_id = models.ForeignKey(Resume)

class Resume(models.Model):
    resume_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    resume_name = models.CharField()
    .... other fields

class Education(models.Model):
    education_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    resume_id = models.ForeignKey(Resume)
    degree_name = models.CharField()
    .... other fields

class Experience(models.Model):
    experience_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    resume_id = models.ForeignKey(Resume)
    company_name = models.CharField()
    .... other fields

class Skills(models.Model):
    skill_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    resume_id = models.ForeignKey(Resume)
    skill_name = models.CharField()
    .... other fields
```

I want to a query-set that against a given job_id in jobapplication model, it should fetch all its related education, experience, skills etc with reference to resume id against job id.
For Now, I do this in Single quires, like i fetch resume_id from job_application then fetch resume details with reference

```
resume_against_job =Jobapplication.objects.get_query_set().get_complete_Jobapplication(job_id)
for resum in resume_against_job:
        resume_dict = {}
        resume_id = resum['resume_id']
        user_id = resum['user_id']
```

then against these `user_id` and `resume_id`, i wrote another queries to fetch user details and their resume detail.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you can only do separate queries on each model if you have the `resume_id` (I see it on each model you have), maybe you can wrap them in one function, but it doesn't get any simpler than that.

I think your fundamental problem is in the database design. If you have `resume_id` in each model, why not merge all of them into `Resume` model? Sounds like they all belong to that model, if each `Education`, `Experience`, `Skill` is `Resume` specific. You only create separate model if resumes share common `Education`, `Experience` or `Skill`, but then they should be foreign keys on the `Resume` model. Also in this case, you only query on `Resume` model and get all other information instead of searching on multiple places.